# Alamofire: Support for uploading multipart forms with text and file parts?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, alamofire

Alamofire now has support for uploading files via a [multipart form](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) upload.

Looking through the MultipartFormData class API, however, I do not see an obvious way of sending heterogeneous data - textural plain/json data along with the assumed binary file data.  In my reading - in the current form, it seems more geared as a multi-file (binary stream) upload without support for text or json parts.

Am I missing something?  How does one upload textual/json data parts along with the assumed file data parts?  Is there any sample code that does this?

To be complete, I have been writing extensions to fill in some of this, but I keep feeling that there has to be an easier way (my changes require some modification to the Alamofire).

That said, and for what it's worth, here is my attempt at a clean form:

```
multipartFormData: { form in
    form.appendBodyPart(Multipart.plain("person", text:"\(last.id)")!)
    form.appendBodyPart(Multipart.json("thing", parameters:parameters)!)
    form.appendBodyPart(fileURL: puppyFile, name: "file") },
```

Obviously a supported solution is better than a re-invented wheel, hence the question.

PS. I am posting this year as per Alamofire documentation, SO is the preferred medium for help and discussion.

Comment: Have read your question twice. Still can not understand what is wrong. Does the code you post work?

Comment: @Avt: thanks for the feedback, I edited to hopefully clarify the distinction between binary parts and the textual parts that I am seeking.  Does it makes more sense now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was not supported at the time of my post, but has been implemented since then, on the `multipart_form` branch, for the 1.3 release which is now currently available.  This related issue is:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/596